# React Object of Objects - How to loop through

Tags: json, reactjs, loops, dictionary, foreach

I have the following encoded JSON:

```
const data = JSON.parse('{"first":{"aaa":"111","bbb":"2222"},"second":{"aaa":"111","bbb":"2222"}}')
```

After decoding as follows:

```
{
  "first": {
    "aaa": "111",
    "bbb": "2222"
  },
  "second": {
    "aaa": "111",
    "bbb": "2222"
  }
}
```

I've then tried a few a number of ways to loop through this data as follows but not work as expected:

```
{Object.keys(data).map((key, value) =>
    console.log(key);
    <li>{value.aaa}</li>
)}
```

I can console.log out the data and see it loops but I can't see to display the aaa or bbb values.

What am I doing wrong here?

thx
Adam

Comment: The second parameter inside map is the index of the element. Change your code to  data[key].aaa inside the li element to get the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for in` loop:

```
{for (key in data) {
    for (innerKey in data[key]) {
        <li>{data[key][innerKey]}</li>
    }
}}
```

The reason we need to use brackets around `key` and `innerKey` is because those properties will need to be computed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable that holds value.

```
var a = {
  "first": {
  "aaa": "111",
  "bbb": "2222"
},
"second": {
 "aaa": "111",
 "bbb": "2222"
 }
}
```

use following to get the keys :

```
 var keys = Object.keys(a);
```

Finally iterate over it :

```
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
    var key = (keys[i]) ; 
    console.log(a[key]) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
{Object.keys(data).map((key, index) =>
    <li key={index}>{data[key].aaa}</li>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to run your code.
It was basically ok, just need to change the property name "key" from .map since it conflicts with a react keyword.

```
 {Object.keys(data).map((label, index) => (
                <div key={index}>{data[label].aaa}</div>
            ))}
```